# Clara rules: Is it possible to extract defrecord-s into a separate Clojure namespace?

Tags: clojure, clara-rule-engine

New facts inserting works fine but I can not find a way to fix defrule-s, e.g.

```
(defrule is-important
  "Find important support requests."
  [SupportRequest (= :high level)]
  =>
  (println "High support requested!"))
```

`[domain/SupportRequest (= :high level)]` doesn't work due to `"Execution error (ClassNotFoundException) at java.net.URLClassLoader/findClass (URLClassLoader.java:436). SupportRequest".`

```clj
(ns clara.compatibility
  (:require [clara.rules.accumulators :as acc]
            [clara.tools.tracing :as tracing]
            [clara.tools.inspect]
            [clara.domain :as domain]
            [clara.rules :refer :all]))
```

The reason why I wanted to extract those defrecords is that the domain is rather big and I wanted to minimize the number of code lines in one file.

Is there any way to do in without falling back to lower-level fact-type-fn and regular Clojure maps?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Given that clara allows to use "clojure records and java beans" i'd be really surprised if they can not come from anywhere. Can you rule the obvious things like: clean, restart repl, etc. just to eliminate all residual stuff.  is the defrecord in the ns working properly - e.g. outside of clara.

Comment: @cfrick  Sorry, just added more info - error is "Execution error (ClassNotFoundException) at java.net.URLClassLoader/findClass (URLClassLoader.java:436). SupportRequest"

Comment: Oh right, you would have to import them (not require)

Comment: @cfrick ouch, thank you. Would you mind to post it as an answer rather than a comment? I'll accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clara expects a class here (I am unaware for the exact reasons; I'd
assume for better Java-interop (as in, using it from Java)).

Since `defrecord`:s result in a class in their respective
namespace/package they are fine here.

Yet if you put them somewhere outside the rules file, you would have to
deal with them as if they were classes: you have to `:import` them
instead of `:require`:ing them.